# Create a result with rows with same ids into columns in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by, pivot

I have a Microsoft SQL Server database table like this:

[image]

And I'm trying to create a view in a way that, rows with the same **from** grouped together and **Type A** and **Type B** values are arranged as columns like below:

[image]

I tried to use several grouping methods and pivoting, but I could get only values in comma-separated as below:

[image]

Is there a way in SQL Server I can achieve the column-oriented result in an efficient way?

Comment: Do a GROUP BY. Use case expressions to do conditional counting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do conditional aggregation:

```
select
    [from],
    max(case when type = 'A' then val end) typeA,
    max(case when type = 'B' then val end) typeB
from mytable
group by [from]
```

Note that `from` is a reserved word in all SQL dialects, hence not a good choice for a column name.